# C++ reverse XOR operator?

Tags: math, hex, xor

I have a hexadecimal number which i XOR with another hexadecimal number.

I only know one of those hexadecimal numbers but i know the result of the XOR operation.

**Example**

> 0x35 ^ x = 0x39

Is there a way to get x?

Comment: x = 0x35 ^ 0x39, a = b ^ c <=> b = a  ^ c <=> c = a ^ b

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get x with

```
x = 0x35 ^ 0x39
```

For XOR :

```
a = b ^ c <=> b = a ^ c <=> c = a ^ b
```